# When to use "essay" vs "assay" (as a verb)?

Tags: differences, verbs, confusables

By the dictionary definition as a verb, I can see that *essay* and *assay* have the same meaning, i.e. "make an effort or attempt".

I'm wondering if they are totally interchangeable, or is there a difference in degree associated with each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The modern meanings for `essay` and `assay` are almost unrelated.  One essays a difficult task; one assays an ore or other material to objectively measure its value.  A essayist is a writer; an assayer is a metallurgist.

Answer (score 6):

Both have the same root, the French *essai* (trial). As verbs with the meaning of “attempt or try”, the *New Oxford American Dictionary* marks *essay* as “formal”, and *assay* as “archaic”. Apart from that, **they are synonymous (and both antiquated)**.

---

*Edit:* regarding modern synonyms of this meaning, one would now say *attempt* or *try*. Other synonyms are *endeavour*, *seek*, *undertake* or *have a go at*.

Comment: If both are antiquated, what would be the apt word to be used today ?

Comment: “attempt or try”

Comment: The verb *assay* is still commonly used in medicine: http://www.medterms.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=8412

Answer (score 1):

The noun "assay" occurs in science, such as a "sequence assay", and scientists often verb such nouns (for example the verb "sequence", such as "we sequenced the human genome").

If you're talking about the verbed noun "assay", then it isn't interchangeable with "essay".